# RamdaJS: Composing an object produces the same "random" results

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I'm playing with Ramda in an attempt to get my head around functional JS.  The following code is an attempt to generate some random search filter objects:

```
var R = require('ramda');
var rWords = require('random-words');

var types = ['keyword', 'phrase', 'domain', 'person'];
var operands = ['AND', 'OR', 'NOT'];

var getRandom = (min=1, max=10) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
var sample = (arr) => arr[getRandom(0, arr.length)];
var chooseWords = (min=1, max=getRandom()) => rWords({min, max, join: ' '});
var chooseWordsFromType = (obj) => {
    var max = obj.type === 'phrase' ? 10 : 1;
    query = chooseWords(1, max);
    return R.merge({query}, obj);
};

var makeFilter = R.compose(
    chooseWordsFromType,
    R.merge({operand: sample(operands)}),
    R.merge({type: sample(types)})
);

var initial = [];
for(var i = 0; i < getRandom(); i++){
    initial.push(makeFilter({}));
}
console.log(initial);
```

The expected outcome should be something like

```
[
  {type: 'keyword', operand: 'AND', query:['something']},
  {type: 'domain', operand: 'AND', query:['something_else']}
]
```

The bug is that everything in `initial` has the exact same operand and type; only the query itself is different.  I guess its memoizing the calls to `sample`, but I don't know why.

As an aside, how can I refactor `chooseWordsFromType` so that it composes without needing to return the object? Or can I?

Comment: This will be much easier to troubleshoot and discuss if you can provide a working example. It's possible that your use of `random-words` is causing an issue, and removing that code would make it easier to reason about what you're trying to accomplish. Can you strip out external dependencies except for Ramda and provide a SO snippet, JS Bin, or similar to demo the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What would you expect from this code?:

```
var defaultOperands = {operand: sample(operands)};
var defaultTypess = {type: sample(types)};

var makeFilter = R.compose(
    chooseWordsFromType,
    R.merge({operand: defaultOperands}),
    R.merge({type: defaultTypes})
);
```

Your code:

```
var makeFilter = R.compose(
    chooseWordsFromType,
    R.merge({operand: sample(operands)}),
    R.merge({type: sample(types)})
);
```

does much the same thing, saying, in essence, "call `sample`, passing in `operands`, make an object out of that, keyed by 'operand'", do something similar with `types` and 'type', and then create a `makeFilter` function which will merge each of these static objects with your input and return the results of passing that to `chooseWordsFromType`.

---

One (untested) way to make it dynamic would be:

```
var makeFilter = R.compose(
    chooseWordsFromType,
    obj => R.merge({operand: sample(operands)}, obj),
    obj => R.merge({type: sample(types)}, obj)
);
```

Comment: Or. as my much less verbose colleague, @buzz-de-cafe, puts it, "`makeFilter` has the random number from `sample` in its closure. `makeFilter` does not re-evaluate the call to `sample` when it is invoked."

Comment: your untested method worked like a charm, and I think I understand what you're saying about the random number from sample not being re-evaluated.  A further question: Is it worth taking this kind of approach to building up an object, or is this something that isn't really what Ramda is for?

Comment: I'm not sure there's a great answer to your question.  Ramda is a collection of utility functions.  They are built to be easily composable, but there's not any specific domains for which they're particularly well-suited or ill-suited.  There is one mismatch between your subject and any functional library, though, and that is in the use of randomness.  Since most FP systems stress referential transparency, any function invoking a call to Random will be strictly verboten.  Still, that should be your own call; it has nothing to do with how you use Ramda.

Comment: The randomness in this instance is just to populate some test data; Basically, I'm trying to play with "building up" an object the way you might compositionally build up a list.

Comment: I think that's perfectly legitimate.  You might want to investigate also **[`R.assoc`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#assoc)** and **[`Lens`es](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/pull/1205)** for other techniques which might help.